# how to create shortcut in folder in android menu. (not on home screen)

Tags: android, eclipse

I am totally newbie and I am not an English native speaker, so please don't yell at me if I do something wrong.

I made an android app in eclipse (nothing special), but I have one problem. I want to add a shortcut in folder so the user can call it from folder. in that folder i will later add more shortcuts. i want to separate my apps from others. this folder and the shortcuts need to be in   main manu.

I tried some codes what I found here in stackoverflow, but I stacked and I don't know how to proceed.

Thanks in forward for anwsers

Comment: i want to create a folder and shortcuts during instalation. just like in windows. you open start menu and you have your own folder with your shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

Though I am not an Android developer, I don't think you have to update anything. Users should just be able to drag your application icon to the home screen. If you want action-specific shortcuts (I.E., go to Wi-Fi settings in the settings app), then please update your question.

Answer (score 0):

> you open start menu and you have your own folder with your shortcuts

In Android, the "start menu" equivalent is called the home screen. There are many, many implementations of a home screen -- dozens that come pre-installed on different devices, and hundreds more than can be downloaded from the Play Store and elsewhere.

Some home screens may have the concept of a "folder", but they may or may not expose an API to developers to control it. Other home screens will not have "folders" at all.

You are welcome to contact each home screen author to find out whether they support the notion of "folders" and whether there is a specific way for your app to create a "folder" and appear inside of it.

Or, you are welcome to build your own home screen, complete with as many folders as you like.